Old Doorknob and Stiff Lock
How to make the locks on these old (vintage?) spindle-style doorknobs (for bedroom doors) less stiff?
I also have a few of these wherein the lock (though I can move it all the way to the right) doesn't actually lock the door.  Is there something I can do (besides replacing the entire doorknob) to get the lock to work again?
These doorknobs are from a house built around 1935.



Update - 09-01-24...
I haven't had a chance to get some graphite dry lubricant yet, but I think I figured out why at least one of the locks was no longer working.  When I disassembled a different (but same type) of doorknob that wasn't locking at all, I noticed that the section of the spindle where the locking mechanism constrains the movement of the spindle had gotten very worn down (over the 50+ years of its life).  So, as a quick fix, I just flipped the spindle, so the interior body / plate component (which contains the locking mechanism) would now have a (relatively) unworn section of spindle to bite into. This seems to have worked!
Here are some pics which should hopefully better illustrate what I'm talking about...



Now, as per JACK, I'm just going to pick up some graphite dry lubricant and hopefully that will resolve the stiffness issues on the various other doorknobs in the house.

I have encountered these in an old home that were tight.  I remover the knobs by loosening the set screws and unscrewing them.  ( The square shaft had threads so the knobs actually screwed on.)  Lubing the workings helped. I used WD40. ( I know some here don't recommend it)  Then when I put the knobs back on I didn't screw them on as tight.  The door worked well. The lock was never an issue, but I suspect for you, based on age,  it will be a broken part.

Loosen the two screws holding it to the door and twist a tiny bit.  It looks like the lock might be catching/not free to fit the square peg into the square hole.

Thanks for the feedback, RMDman and crip659.  Really appreciate it.

If you really want them to work like new, remove them from the door and wire brush/clean all the parts to remove any rust and then get some normal duty oil or graphite dry lubricant and oil the parts and re-assemble into the door. If you're not up to doing all this work, spray some lubricating oil into all the moving parts without disassembling and work the parts back and forth. If the locks don't latch enough to lock the doors, you'll probably have to adjust the strike plate, shim it out a bit.

Is it worth trying to apply the graphite dry lubricant without disassembling?  Or would you not recommend that?

It might work a little where the bolt exits the door but other than that, no.  If you just remove the handles, which is easy, you could apply some of it to the bolt chamber which could help.

I've had good luck with puffing powdered graphite in through the latch slot (while the latch is pulled in to make a gap).  Spray lubes may work as well, but I would recommend dry silicone so it doesn't risk gumming up (then you would have to take it apart).

I wonder if some silicone lube wouldn't work as well, e.g. Blaster or SiliKroil.

@Huesmann  These would probably work too being a penetrating lube.
